# ESXi 5 NFS mount with credentials

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, mount

Is it possible for an ESXi 5 host to mount a remote NFS share using credentials other than root?  (The default)?  If so, how would one setup those credentials and mount from VSphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no user authentication support for NFS using credentials.

The authentication is based on the source IP address of the NFS client (ie: the ESXi host) and the actual mount point.

Maybe you mean Samba Shares (aka windows shares)?
Those are not supported on ESXi. Only NFS and iSCSI are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Source for Basic connection command: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc_50%2Fcli_manage_storage.6.6.html

```
esxcli <conn_options> storage nfs add --host=dir42.eng.vmware.com --share=/<mount_dir> --volume-name=nfsstore-dir42
```

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc_50%2Fcli_overviews.3.8.html

Source for Basic: Connection Options (second value in the connection command)

```
- -username <u_name>
VI_USERNAME=<u_name>

- -password <passwd>
VI_PASSWORD=<passwd>
```